# Codeigniter URL route using 404_override

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a very big application (many controllers and modules), within the application there are articles (posts), and I want to put the URL like:
**example.com/[category_name]/[article_name]** ie:
**example.com/gadgets/top-ten-coolest-gadgets-of-2018**

I have a controller called Content so the URL was set up like this:
**example.com/content/[category_name]/[article_name]**

I want to remove **"/content/"** from the URL, so, first I tried to add the following in routes.php:

```
$ route ['(:any)/(:any)'] = '/content/categoryArticles/$1/$2';
```

But the rest of the controllers stop working, so I had to add all them in routes.php (and there are many).

I want to try to use 404_override as a default route when the URL does not find the controller and redirect all to **/content/categoryArticles** ie, do this:

```
route ['404_override'] = '/content/categoryArticles/'
```

and in the categoryArticles function, explode the URL by segments and determine the parameters.

This is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

If you use (:any) as your first parameter then all controller/folder will be override by routes. however you can use an alias first then the following parameters so that it wont affect other controllers.

```
$routes['post/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'content/categoryArticles/$1/$2';
```

Unless you have a constant list of category then you can initialize those categories then add it to routes

```
$categories = array('gadgets', 'review', 'news', 'sports', 'business');

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $route["{$category}/(:any)"] = "content/categoryArticles/{$category}/$1";
}
```

Comment: Category is a parameter, sorry, I think I did not explain it very well. I updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Those options I had already considered, because that is how it is originally.

I need to remove /content/ or /posts/ from the URL, I mean, the category name like the first segment element of the URL.

The only option I see to be able to do this, is to use the 404_override route as a default, but I do not know if this is a good practice